# bookdown rendering first page of chapters on left page rather than right page - is this normal?

Tags: pdftex, bookdown

I just noticed in rendering a pdf book in r bookdown that new chapters start on the left page rather than the right page. This even includes the sample file created whenever a  new r bookdown project is created.

I thought generally that a new book chapter always start on the page on the right in printed books. Obviously right and left oriented pages are important for printing books because the left and right margins are alternated in positions to allow for printing not to be unreadable because of the spine of the book.

Is this a bug in R bookdown? Or is there a way of forcing the 1st page of a chapter to always start on the right side page?

If this isnt the place to ask this question, please forgive and let me know?

Comment: it depends on the class, standard `book` for example has an `openany` option to allow this.

Comment: Note book classes have wider margins on the _outer_ edge: the larger margin is for your thumbs not for binding. Typically the inner margin is around half the outer one so you get three equal white spaces across a two page spread.